# Detect when SplitContainer collapsed changes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a SplitContainer I want to catch the Panel2 collapsing and expanding events.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Posting this for others that might be hunting for the same answer as I was.

Unfortunately SplitContainer doesn't offer any direct events for the collapsed events. What I have found useful is to monitor the SizeChanged and/or ClientSizeChanged events of the OPPOSITE panel to the one you're collapsing.

Meaning, if I am interested in monitoring collapses of Panel2, I would subscribe to ClientSizeChanged events for Panel1.

In practice I would recommend monitoring the ClientSizeChanged for both panels of the SplitContainer to guarantee you don't miss any initialization or direct splitter movements.

In the below example I have a toggle button (btnToggle) that I want the Checked state to follow the visibility of Panel2 in the SplitContainer:

```
private void splitContainer_Panel2_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        btnToggle.Checked = !splitContainer.Panel2Collapsed;
}

private void splitContainer_Panel1_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        btnToggle.Checked = !splitContainer.Panel2Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an event exactly for that, but that's because you should know when it's getting collapsed when the code it run:

```
splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = true;
// do your stuff
```

Otherwise, you can watch for the `SplitterMoved` or `SplitterMoving` events on the SplitContainer control.

Comment: SplitterMoved  work only when transfer from colapsed mode to uncolapse, SplitterMoving doesn't fire on the colapsing and uncolapsing any idea . I know Panel1Collapsed  and Panel2Collapsed any idea

Comment: @AMH There isn't a way for the user to collapsed a panel, which means you have control of it.  When you set `Panel1Collapsed=true;` then you should do whatever it is you want to do.  It's hard to understand the problem.  Maybe post some code of what you are trying to do (edit your question).

Answer (score 1):

```
splitContainer.Panel1.VisibleChanged += (s, e) => { bool isPanel1Collapsed = splitContainer.Panel1Collapsed; };
```

Answer (score 1):

In the internal implementation, when a panel in a `SplitContainer` is collapsed, is `Visible` property is set to `false` and vice-versa. It is therefore possible to detect the changes when a panel is collapsed by handling the `VisibleChanged` event of the desired panel.

The catch is that the `SplitterPanel` class doesn't expose this event. However, since it inherits the `Panel` class which exposes this event, you can cast to a `Panel` and handle the event from there as demonstrated in the sample code below.

```
private void Initialize()
{
    split = new SplitContainer();
    ((Panel)split.Panel1).VisibleChanged += splitPanel1_Collapsed;
}

private void splitPanel1_Collapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var panel = (SplitterPanel)sender;
    var panelCollapsed = !panel.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The only problem with the above solution is that the "panel.Visible" syntax does not exist in my visual studio.

Comment: Which version of visual Studio are you using? I have tested it in VS2015, VS2017 and VS2019 and it works with no modification.

Comment: My visual studio version is 2005. Maybe I should switch to the newer version. Thanks for your attention.