# C# winforms. Drag events

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

I need to run code when I dismiss(end) dragging click. How this event is called?

Here is main example, please find the below screenshot for more information:

[image: before drag]

I made that I can drag the car on other picture boxes like below this:

[image: after drag]

Repeat again - I need to know what EVENT is then you dismiss to drag on picture box?

Comment: Do you mean when its dropped? or when the drag is rejected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no event for when the drag is released on a control, but you don't really need one. This is what I did to simulate what (I think) you're looking for. I used code courtesy of [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16384982/386703)

```
private Point? _mouseLocation;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.pictureBox1.MouseDown += this.pictureBox1_MouseDown;
    this.pictureBox1.MouseUp += this.pictureBox1_MouseUp;
    this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += this.pictureBox1_MouseMove;    
}

void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{  
    if ( this._mouseLocation.HasValue)
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Left = e.X + this.pictureBox1.Left - this._mouseLocation.Value.X;
        this.pictureBox1.Top = e.Y + this.pictureBox1.Top - this._mouseLocation.Value.Y;
    }
}
void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this._mouseLocation = null;
}

void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if you've left-clicked if you want
    this._mouseLocation = e.Location;

}
```

Setting the mouse location to null with `this._mouseLocation = null;` is your "drag released" code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you talking about [DragDrop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop.aspx). You can find example here: [How to: Enable Drag-and-Drop Operations with the Windows Forms RichTextBox Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw1hc6t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If he's talking about dragging the `PictureBox` itself, `DragDrop` is not the right event. That event is fired when something is dragged into the control and dropped, not when the control itself is dragged.

Comment: @Brandon exactly. Can you help me? :)