# Moving a control by dragging it with the mouse in VB

Tags: wpf, vb.net

In the final answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384903/moving-a-control-by-dragging-it-with-the-mouse-in-c-sharp), Paweł Wojda posts a general way to move controls with a mouse.  However, I'm working in VB and have been unable to translate his approach because there are no equivalents to control.location and control.update.  How can this same functionality be ported to VB.

Comment: That question is using a Windows Forms project (also available in VB.NET), but based on your most used tags I guess you're using WPF? If this is the case, the equivalent to WinForms's `Control.Location` property is [`Control.Margin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_FrameworkElement_Margin) (top and left, specifically) in WPF, and the equivalent to `Update` is `InvalidateVisual` (although there is no need to call either in this case, so you can just ignore it).

Comment: For future reference, Windows Forms (WinForms) is the first of the two technologies that can be used to create standard, close to native Windows applications. It is based on Win32 and renders most of its content using your CPU. || Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) is the second of the two, which came along afterwards and is more of a specialized technology that uses DirectX (and therefore your GPU) to render its content.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes, I should have added "wpf" which I just did.  I'll try margin.

Comment: @VisualVincent  If you post you first reply as an answer, I'll mark it as having answered my question.

Comment: Glad I could help, and sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you linked is using a Windows Forms project, however based on your most used tags I guess you're using WPF.

The equivalent to WinForms's `Control.Location` property is [`Control.Margin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_FrameworkElement_Margin) in WPF (top and left, specifically).

The, somewhat, equivalent to `Control.Update` is `Control.InvalidateVisual`. Although, in this case there is no need to call either, so you can just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

`dim down as new boolean`
On mouse down event :

```
Down = true
```

On mouse up event :

```
Down =false
```

On mouse move event :

```
If down = true Then
      Me.location = cursor.position
 End if
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer applies only to WinForms, but like the tags indicate the OP is using WPF. These are two different GUI technologies that only share a few similarities. In either case, please make sure to read through the entire question thorougly before answering, as the OP explicitly stated that `Control.Location` (which refers to the same property as `Me.Location`) doesn't exist. Thank you!