# Any trick to use opacity on a panel in Visual Studio Window Form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel, opacity

I recently started exploring Visual Studio.
I was trying to create a slide menu. More specifically, when the user would press the button a submenu would pop up to the right. To achieve that i have placed a `Panel` to resize itself. Apart from functionality i wanted to add a bit more design and make the `Panel` appear a bit faded.

I know that `Panels` in Visual studio do not have opacity, but i was thinking if anyone knows a way-trick-idea about how it can be achieved. I tried a `Picture Box` but that too didn't have Opacity as a property. I avoided to use the regular `Menu`object that visual studio offers because i wanted to add more design. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set the opacity or transparency of a Panel in WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463363/how-can-i-set-the-opacity-or-transparency-of-a-panel-in-winforms)

Comment: I have seen this, but this didn't work for me, that's why i asked. Thx

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The poster knows that there is no opacity for controls.

Comment: Just what shall be below the Panel or whatever control you will use? What shall shine through? Other Controls? Dynamic content?

Answer (score 30):

1. Create a class that inherits from [`Panel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/panel-control-windows-forms?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).
2. Set the [`ControlStyle.Opaque`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlstyles?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) for control in constructor using [`SetStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.8%3FWT.mc_id%3DDT-MVP-5003235).

> If true, the control is drawn opaque and the background is not
>   painted.

2. Override [`CreateParams`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.createparams?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and set [`WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) style for it.

> Specifies that a window created with this style is to be transparent.
>   That is, any windows that are beneath the window are not obscured by
>   the window. A window created with this style receives WM_PAINT
>   messages only after all sibling windows beneath it have been updated.

3. Create an `Opacity` property that accepts values from 0 to 100 that will be used as alpha channel of background.
4. Override [`OnPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and fill the background using an alpha enabled `Brush` that is created from `BackGroundColor` and `Opacity`.

**Complete Code**

```
public class ExtendedPanel : Panel
{
    private const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
    public ExtendedPanel()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
    }

    private int opacity = 50;
    [DefaultValue(50)]
    public int Opacity
    {
        get
        {
            return this.opacity;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0 || value > 100)
                throw new ArgumentException("value must be between 0 and 100");
            this.opacity = value;
        }
    }
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
            return cp;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(this.opacity * 255 / 100, this.BackColor)))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. I implemented it with a timer so the opacity would start at 100 and go down to 0. However it is flickering like crazy. Any idea how to get a smooth animation?

Comment: @ChrisB I'll check it using a timer, but  maybe you find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34338985/3110834) useful.

Comment: @ChrisB By the way, I used [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39068779/3110834) for a case which I needed a semi-transparent overlay in windows forms. (It may sounds irrelevant, but using a Form as an overlay is a more reliable solution in some cases.)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work above a `SplitPanel` unfortunately.

Comment: Works in general, but when I put the cursor over the not-overlayed part of the "button on form", the button is brought into the foreground and stays there. How can I fix that? It should return into the background automatically when then mouse leaves it.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss That's why I included the picture. I'll take another look at it to find out if there is a workaround or not.

Comment: I can't get this to work when I run the app, It displays in the design view, but not when I run the application?

Comment: Just want to add a few notes about using the above code block.

1) Any control behind that is foregrounded needs manually backgrounded and may require a Form.Refresh(); to force a repaint of the form and all its children.

Answer (score 3):

To make a control "transparent", you should paint the right area of its parent onto the control. That's what the `Button` does before it draws its content so the rounded corners will be transparent.

To mimic semi-transparency, you can paint the form onto the panel, and then draw something with Alpha:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    PaintTransparentBackground(panel1, e);
    using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, panel1.BackColor)))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.ClipRectangle);
    }
}

private static void PaintTransparentBackground(Control c, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (c.Parent == null || !Application.RenderWithVisualStyles)
        return;

    ButtonRenderer.DrawParentBackground(e.Graphics, c.ClientRectangle, c);
}
```

[image: Semi-transparent panel]

Please note that the `ButtonRenderer.DrawParentBackground` does not paint the **controls** of the form, which overlap with the panel, but only the background of the form.

Comment: If there are controls to be overlapped you can still get the target in a bitmap with drawtobitmap. The animation will look like shite in winforms, though..

Answer (score 0):

Set any color at the panel. For example, black, after which you just need to register the TransparencyKey shape and select the color you want to make transparent:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            panel1.BackColor = Color.Black; 
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.Black;
        }
```