# Show a Label with semi-transparent BackColor above other controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've got a **custom control** with two **PictureBox controls** that are **animated** and a **label control** over them.

The **child indexes** are set so that label is always on top but the picture boxes are interchanging so when animated they display different images each time.

As I understand, label needs to have a parent control on top of which it can support a semi transparent color (Argb). Since the label has active picture box as its parent it will also be animated with which is not what I want at all.

Is there a way to fix a child position relative to parents parent?

Comment: You cannot achieve this effect in WinForms as the platform does not support true control variable opacity. "Transparent backgrounds" are implemented as a hack that makes the root parent (the underlying `Form`) repaint it's background. You cannot successfully layer multiple transparent controls on top.

Comment: @Dai - I thought so too but hoped for better ;). Is there any other way to achieve similar effect using win forms. I've seen DevXpress people make controls with similar effect so I wanted to give it a try. Any other solution that do not include WPF or going from win forms?

Comment: @Dino Let me know if I understand your question correctly: Do you need to have a transparent label above your picture box that only shows the text?

Comment: @Reza Aghaei - Not quite. I want a semi-transparent color over animated picture boxes. I want to create something similar to windows tile.

Comment: @Dino, can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: @Dino Being animated makes no difference. Do you need semi-transparent background color for the label or or semi-transparent fore color for `Label`?

Comment: @Reza Aghaei - Background color only

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To have a transparent label control, you can override the [`OnPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method and draw all controls that intersects with label, at last draw the background and text of the label.

Also when moving your picture boxes, don't forget to call the [`Invalidate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method of the transparent label.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Sample Implementation**

```
public class TransparentLabel : Label
{
    public TransparentLabel()
    {
        this.transparentBackColor = Color.Blue;
        this.opacity = 50;
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Parent != null)
        {
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(Parent.Width, Parent.Height))
            {
                Parent.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                      .Where(c => Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(c) > Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(this))
                      .Where(c => c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(this.Bounds))
                      .OrderByDescending(c => Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(c))
                      .ToList()
                      .ForEach(c => c.DrawToBitmap(bmp, c.Bounds));


                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, -Left, -Top);
                using (var b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(this.Opacity, this.TransparentBackColor)))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, this.ClientRectangle);
                }
                e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, this.ClientRectangle, this.ForeColor, Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
    }

    private int opacity;
    public int Opacity
    {
        get { return opacity; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0 && value <= 255)
                opacity = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Color transparentBackColor;
    public Color TransparentBackColor
    {
        get { return transparentBackColor; }
        set
        {
            transparentBackColor = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public override Color BackColor
    {
        get
        {
            return Color.Transparent;
        }
        set
        {
            base.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To make it full transparent background, set opacity to 0. Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: I will try it in the next few hours when I find the time and will make a reply with the results. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome and Thank you for your feedback :) The screenshot has taken from the execution and it worked properly here.

Comment: I'm a noob so this was a little bit over my head. The way I implemented your solution didn't work well. I know that I need to call `Invalidate()` on the `TransparentLabel` every time background changes but I'm a little bit lost since this is all new to me. I've been using [link](https://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/) dot-net-transition to experiment and  learn about animations and implementing your solution in this sample project [link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/jvgq5u4pxrwsqv2) was as described. The last link is the sample project so you can see what mean.

Comment: You should test the answer in a simple test case, for example programmatically using a `Timer` change the position and `BackGround` of the `PictureBox` and you will see the solution work properly. And then you can try to apply the answer to your project.

Comment: I know that it works well. Your solution is awesome. The problem is the transition library that I'm using is confusing for me and cant find a way to call Invalidate() inside its moving function. Link is in the previous comment. [link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/jvgq5u4pxrwsqv2)

Comment: @Dino thank you for your kind feedback. For a simple test, I made those pictire boxes public and then in the form, I subscribed for `PositionChaged` event of them and callled ` this.transparentLabel1.Invalidate();` and it worked properly.

Comment: But it's better to subscribe for the event of both picture boxes in the user control and when you received the `LocationChanged` raise a new custom event and subscribe for this event on your form and put `invalidate` code there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98344/discussion-between-dino-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I updated onpaint method a bit. You also may find this post helpful: [How to make two transparent layer with c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36102074/3110834)

Comment: This answer has been here for 9 years, Why Microsoft did not integrate this class in .Net framework already?

Comment: @Dohab Well, WinForms doesn't support opacity for child controls. So this implementation is just a hack. If you extensively have such requirements, you may want to use WPF or other frameworks.