# Use opacity on a panel and label in Visual Studio Windows Forms, C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to use opacity on a panel and a label using WinForms with C#, i been able to change panel opacity, in this way panel opacity allows the PictureBox content behind the panel can be seen, i use the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32402532/6068130'), the problem is i need to place a label above the panel, and i need the label background looks like the panel opacity, if the label Backgroud color is "Transparent", it looks white, and if i try to use the same method i use with the panel, on the label, it does not look the same, it is any way the panel background and the label background look with the same opacity?

Actually, it looks like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sABpG.png)

The panel is the one it looks like white, docked to the bottom, above it's the big Label, that's the one with "Transparent" color background, and the smallest label, it's the one i try to do with this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34338985/6068130)

Very grateful for any help you can give me

This is how i add the label to the panel

```
Label newLabel = new Label();
newLabel.Text = "DISHONORED";
newLabel.Location = new Point(100,100);
newLabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
panel3.Controls.Add(newLabel);
```

Comment: Transparency only works for nested controls. is the label nested in the Panel?

Comment: I believe it is, this is the way i add the label, panel3 is the panel with opacity, i edit the question with the code