# How to create a winform user control whose background color is a partially transparent, black color?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, vsto

I have an outlook plugin, in which I load winform usercontrols in custompane.When user tries to upload a file to the server, I want to show progress of the upload using a progress bar shown in the center of the pane, with rest of the pane area darkend but still tranparent to some extent.Here is a screen shot to give an idea of the UI.[image]

So, how do I make background of a winform usercontrol partially transparent.

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358500/making-a-control-transparent

Comment: You may find this post helpful: [Any trick to use opacity on a panel in Visual Studio Window Form?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32402532/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Color.FromArgb` for background color of your control.

for example `Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Doesn't work.It is totally opaque, I need it to be transparent.