# C# Transparency Isn't Affecting Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a panel (OverPanel) that is in the very front of the form. I am using it as a entered form/exited form panel. Under the panel, there are other controls that I want to be visible, so I set the panel on top to transparent. The problem is, it is not turning transparent but is adherently taking the color of the form (Control). Here is the Hierarchy of the form.

OverPanel Panel Panel
rcmMenuPanel Panel
--- rcmMenuLabel Label
rcmSetupPanel Panel
--- rcmSetupPanel Label

What I want to happen is the OverPanel to be transparent and the rcmMenu and Setup Panels to show but what happens is, the rcmMenu and rcmSetup Panels won't show and the OverForm's Background color is the form color when set to transparent. I don't want this to happen, so how do I fix it?

Comment: Setting `BackColor` to `Transparent` just means showing parent's background. It doesn't mean real transparency.  As an option take a look at this post: [Any trick to use opacity on a panel in Visual Studio Window Form?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32402532/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei I tried doing it that way, but it's not working. whenever you switch the color, the panel gets more opaque.

Comment: Just refresh the panel when needed. Also see another example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40209045/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei I figured out the problem. It was the opacity that was set to .5 instead of 0

Comment: Good job :) The second link which I provided doesn't have opacity and is transparent by default.

Comment: You may find both linked posts useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first link that @Reza Aghaei sent me worked!

Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32402532/6804700