# How to make semi-transparent form supporting gradient images

Tags: c#, winforms, transparent

hello in my project i have this form:

[image: form design]

The transparenctkey of the form is set to Wheat, so it's backcolor.
But when i try to create pictureboxes with semi transparent images, the transparency key doesnt work in the gradient.

Is there any way i can make the wheat color disappear completely?
I just want the image to be visible

This is my current progress:

[image: current gradient]

Comment: transparency key and gradients do not work together.

Comment: If you want to genenrate that kind of effect with a Form, you need a per-pixel-alpha Layered Form, then paint on it a Bitmap with alpha channel and semi-transparent pixels. Note that this kind of Form doesn't support child Controls -- In a WinForms Project, you can show a WPF Window without any problem

Comment: You can take a look at a WinForms and a WPF example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51018033/3110834)